# Adding attributes to HTML tags with PHP

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is change

```
<input name="username">
```

to something like

```
<input name="username" class="empty">
```

if the form is empty.

Here's the PHP I've got for it in a separate file:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

if(empty($username)) {
  // add HTML attribute to tag
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Has the tag already been outputted?

Comment: check this out http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Comment: Like does it already exist or are you creating the tag from scratch?

Comment: I would suggest moving that portion of the HTML to where your PHP logic is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_btn'])) {
 $class = 'class="empty"';
}
?>

<form method="post" action="#">
    <input name="username" <?php if (!empty( $class )){echo $class ;} ?> >
    <input type="submit" name="save_btn" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: Makes sense, but that's kinda a lot of "empty"s in one statement.  :)

Comment: I agree, its too ugly. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that i suggest:
After submiting the form ,in action.php you will check if username is empty,if it's empty , you will redirect to index.php page with a variable in the url that indicates if field is empty or not(you can also use sessions).

index.php page :

```
    <?php 

        if (isset($_GET['empty'] )){$empty="class='empty'";}
        else {
              $empty="";
             }

     ?>

    <form method="post" action="action.php">
    <input name="username" <?php echo $empty; ?> />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" />
    </form>
```

Your action.php page:

```
    <?php
     $username = $_POST['username'];

     if(empty($username)) {
        header('location:index.php?empty=1');
     }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `echo` if the form doesn't already exist.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];

if(empty($username)) {
  // add HTML attribute to tag
  echo "<input name=\"username\" class=\"empty\">";
} else {
  echo "<input name=\"username\">";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a form that sends to itself? Then try to use the PHP directly in the HTML like this

```
<input name="username" class=" <?=(empty($_POST['username'])?"empty":"";?> " />
```

by using a shortened if-statement the script checks for an empty username field and then outputs the string "empty" in the classes attribute.

Offtopic: use trim() to check if the field is really empty, and remove whitespace.