# Add attribute to a html element from php if else condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I have 2 database table. One is for menu name and another is for child menu name. Some menus have no child menu. I want to create a navigation menu where it will check either the menu has children or not. If it has children it will add data-toggle="dropdown" to that menu so the child menu can be seen in the dropdown box. Here is my code, I am not getting the idea why my code is not working or how my logic will be in HTML.

```js
function myFunction()
{
  $(".dropdown-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/index')?>">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/logos/logo.png" alt="LogoFOR2401" title="LogoFOR2401">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <?php foreach ($navigationmenu as $navigationmenu_item): ?>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/menu')?>/<?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuID']; ?>" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" name="<?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuName']; ?>" id="navbarDropdownBlog" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuName']; ?></a>                      
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                            <?php foreach ($submenu as $submenu_item): ?>
                                <?php if($navigationmenu_item['MenuID'] == $submenu_item['MenuID']) {?>        
                                    echo "<script type="text/javascript">myFunction();</script>";
                                    <!--echo "function myFunction();";-->
                                    <!--echo "</script>";-->
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/submenu')?>/<?php echo $submenu_item['SubMenuID']; ?>"><?php echo $submenu_item['SubMenuName']; ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>  
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: why are you injecting Javascript to do this? It should just be some fairly simple PHP. And the script will do this action to all elements with the dropdown-toggle class anyway, not just one.

Comment: Could you please show me an example for this? @ADyson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding attributes to HTML tags with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305216/adding-attributes-to-html-tags-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. Since you exited from script execution mode with `?>`, you shouldn't use `echo`. Just put the HTML there.
2. Your function doesn't add the class only to the current menu, it adds the class to *all* preceding elements with `class="dropdown-toggle"`.
3. You're using `id="navbarDropdownBlog"` each time through the loop. IDs should be unique.

You should do the check in PHP, rather than running a function to add the class.

```
<?php foreach ($navigationmenu as $navigationmenu_item):
    $submenus = array_filter($submenu, function($submenu_item) use ($navigationmenu_item) {
        return $submenu_item['MenuID'] == $navigationmenu_item['MenuID'];
    });
    $data = empty($submenus) ? '' : 'data-toggle="dropdown"';
    ?>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/menu')?>/<?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuID']; ?>" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" name="<?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuName']; ?>" id="navbarDropdownBlog-<?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuID']; ?>" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" <?php echo $data; ?>><?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuName']; ?></a>                      
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog-<?php echo $navigationmenu_item['MenuID']; ?>">
            <?php foreach ($submenus as $submenu_item): ?>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/submenu')?>/<?php echo $submenu_item['SubMenuID']; ?>"><?php echo $submenu_item['SubMenuName']; ?></a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

To solve problem 3, I appended the menu ID to the ID.

Comment: Actually, it solves my main problem. Thanks for your help. @Barmar